# How to configure network interface on Ubuntu Server 18.04 using netplan on OVH?

Tags: virtual-machine, ovh

I would like to install an Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a VM using my dedicated server on SoYouStart (low cost OVH service).

But, while I configure the network address like I do it on previous Ubuntu OSes (there is no documentation on the OVH website), my VM doesn't reach any ip.

Answer (score 1):

Here is their instructions in English:
https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/dedicated/network-bridging/

And here is an example:

```
cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml 

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s10f0:
      addresses:
      - 142.44.185.104/32
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 213.186.33.99
        search: []
      optional: true
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 54.39.19.254
          on-link: true
```

Answer (score 0):

It was be resolved on another other forum, so in order to help people to find the solution more easily, I put [the link here](https://community.ovh.com/t/config-netplan-pour-ubuntu-18-dans-une-vm-sur-une-ip-failover/8291) (french version) !

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

https://support.ovhcloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000923690-Connecting-an-Ubuntu-18-04-VM-to-the-Internet-Using-VMware-ESXi-6-5

During installation in VMware, using the Ubuntu Server 18.04 ISO, you can switch to the prompt using Alt+2 and configuring the network as described in the article above.